# window.postMessage() to send data once the data exists

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, postmessage

I'm sending data between a parent window and an embedded `<iframe>` using [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). The parent window listens for a "mounted" message from the `<iframe>`, and sends a response message with a JavaScript object `model` as the data.

Here's the parent window event listener for the "mounted" message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (hasOwnProperty.call(event.data, 'mounted')) {
    $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage({ model }, '*');
  }
});
```

The `<iframe>` may send the "mounted" message several times in one session, and the parent window needs to respond with `model` each time.

However, on the initial page load, the parent window asynchronously retrieves `model` from an external API, which could resolve before or after the parent window receives a "mounted" message.

```
let model = {};
axios.get('/api/model')
  .then((response) => {
    model = response.data;
  });
```

So, if the parent window received a "mounted" message before the model exists, I want my code to wait until model does exist and then send the response. How can I achieve this? I assume it's going to involve changing my `postmessage({ model }, '*')` call into a Promise, but I'm not sure how to attach that Promise to make it wait for the `axios.get` call to complete.

I'm aware of how [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works, but that wouldn't really work since the "mounted" message can be sent multiple times in a window session.

### One solution

While writing this question, I realized that I could write a function that sends `model` only if `model` [isn't empty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isEmpty), which both my "mounted" event listener and my asynchronous data retrieval could call. So, the message is always posted when the data is loaded from the external API (and it doesn't matter if the `<iframe>` hasn't mounted), and the event listener only responds once the model has loaded. Here's the complete code for the solution:

```
function postModel(model) {
  if (!_.isEmpty(model)) {
    $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage({ model }, '*');
  }
}

let model = {};
axios.get('/api/model')
  .then((response) => {
    model = response.data;
    postModel(model);
  });

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (hasOwnProperty.call(event.data, 'mounted')) {
    postModel(model);
  }
});
```

This works for my purposes, but I'd still be interested to see if there is an async/await approach that would be better here.

Comment: why not just add to a queue if its empty, then on the success function of the get request, dump everything in the queue off to the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would find want you need with frameTalk.js. 
FrameTalk supports Promises between iframes. So, you would do smth like that

```
    frameTalk.sendPromise(window.top, "myFrameID", "methodNameToRun", ["methodAttributesToPass"])
.then(doOnSuccess, doOnFail);
```

see more at
https://github.com/inedu/frameTalk

Comment: Thanks! I'd come across frameTalk, but wanted to know if there was a way to do this without relying on another dependency. I'll look more into frameTalk, though.